# Apps only starting with elevated privileges

Tags: windows, administrator, privileges

Three desktop application, namely signal, discord, bilibili are not responding when starting with normal privileges

No error message was printed out, nor is there a verbose option starting these apps in the cli

I tweak my pc settings regularly, registry, group policies, and services and i think it would be impractical to replicate the issue

Ive tried restarting, reinstalling (the installer does not respond without privileges) and the issue persist.

The privileges on the app folders looks normal.

Can i get some help on how to further troubleshoot this issue?

Window 11 Pro 23H2, Asus Motherboard

Comment: "I tweak my pc settings regularly" - how are we supposed to help in such a case?

Comment: Yeah, i supposed so, so im here to ask for ways to troubleshoot, by maybe getting any info regarding the problem. Right now i have zero info to start troubleshooting, so my problem is what can i do to find more info about it?

Comment: Without more info (which might anyway be too complicated to find), I suggest doing [Repair Install](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-perform-a-repair-upgrade-using-the-windows/35160fbe-9352-4e70-9887-f40096ec3085). This will ensure that Windows components are coherent and in a known state. It's the same as doing a major Windows upgrade and will keep your apps and most settings.